# ASP.Net VB - Change rows on gridview depending on SQL Query Result

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

Im trying to change the information on each row depending on the result from the query. Im thinking that at the minute my problem is that I'm only returning the first result from the query into the result.

e.g. query returns row 1 with '1232' row 2 '1243' but result is only ever set to '1232'

I could be wrong but its why I'm here :)

Comment: Since you are proposing that your SQL might be wrong, can you post that too? If it contains sensitive information, feel free to dull it down.

Comment: Also, in my experience, it is much easier to simply have the lblstatus already in your gridview template, and rather than adding the control conditionally when each row is databound, simply changing it's contents when need be.

Comment: Here is the SQL:
  
Dim statement As String = "select tblCustomer.customerID from tblCustomer INNER JOIN tblAccount ON tblCustomer.customerID = tblAccount.customerID INNER JOIN tblAccountStatus ON tblAccount.accountID = tblAccountStatus.accountID WHERE (tblAccountStatus.status = 'deactivated')"

Answer (score 2):

You say that your SQL returns multiple rows, but are using the `ExecuteScalar()` to run it.  ExecuteScalar will only return a single result, ie the first column of the first row.  Sounds like you need to fill a datatable using a `SQLDataAdapter` or something else to do what you're looking for.

Also it would be beneficial if you included your SQL statement as rlb indicated.

Comment: Okay ive tried this and still no joy. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

 

Dim result As SqlDataReader = command3.ExecuteReader()
            While result.Read()
                Dim IDRes As String = CStr(result("customerID"))

                If IDRes = variable Then
                    temp = "Yes"
                    labelstatus.Text = temp
                Else
                    temp = "No"
                    labelstatus.Text = temp
                End If
            End While

Comment: Im sorry, couldnt get the pasted code to edit correct format :(

Comment: Karl, code in the comments will not format correctly, you'll need to edit the question up above for that.  As for your current problem, I see that the function you pasted was grdView_RowDataBound, it would appear that the data has *already* been bound to the gridView, so why are you re-querying against the server?  If it's already databound then you should be able to reference that databound object that's already in memory.  I guess without knowing more about how you're program is structured and your intentions it's sort of difficult to recommend a solution.